# Access denied when user has read-only access

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, site-collection, access-denied

Strange issue I have here. Our users get access denied message to a site collection (top site, nothing above) when I grant them read-only access.

1. I add them  to the visitors group that has read permissions -> no
   access
2. I add them to the members group that has edit permissions ->
   access
3. I change the permissions of the members groups to read -> no
   access

Can someone please advise what goes wrong?

Comment: You've got broken inheritance and they're making a request to something they can't access. Try having them navigate to `_layouts/viewlsts.aspx` and see if they can access that.

Comment: No, finally, we checked the master page out and in again, and started working.

Comment: So close the question so people don't waste their time coming here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a few minute after posting this question, we tried to check out the master page, check in again (did nothing else) and suddenly the permissions started to work.